# jQuery & Ajax with Codeigniter - cannot seem to print the $_GET array in the controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, codeigniter

I have a form that after so many seconds automatically saves the form to a database (well that is my intention)

The script below grabs the values in an jQuery AJAX request and sends this to a controller - but whenever I try to var_dump the values it doesnt seem to work from the serialised array. I can see the parameters are there when I view FireBug in Firefox but cannot seem to print the array - can anyone explain why?

```
// view logic
var t = setTimeout("autosave()", 10000); 
$.ajax( 
{ 
    type: "GET", 
    url: "/questionnaires/autosave", 
    data: $("form").serialize(), 
    cache: false, 
    success: function(msg) {
        return false;
    }
});

// controller logic
function autosave()
{
    $str = parse_str( $this->input->get_post('form') );
    var_dump($str); // intend to do an insert query here to the db
}
```

Comment: use `$this->input->post()` instead.

Comment: try to use `type: "POST"` because passing data with GET make conflicts with `routes` config (not all time)

Comment: OMG - spent ages on that too! Such a simply minute little fix.. why didn't I think of that lol!
Cheers Gavin - much appreciated!

P.S How do I accept your answer? I cannot see the tick icon?

Comment: Just a side note, don't pass strings to `setTimeout`, it uses `eval`!  Pass functions instead.  `var t = setTimeout(autosave, 10000); `

Comment: @Rocket good call thanks for that!

Comment: what is `$this->input->get_post('form');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely dont have `query_string` enabled in your config.php.

As a result you wont be able to use `GET` reliably. Your best option is to change `type: "GET",` to `type: "POST",`.

Then use `$this->input->post()` to access post variables. You can reference this information from the Codeigniter Documentation:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

> ### $this->input->post()
>
> The first parameter will contain the name of the POST item you are
>   looking for:
>
> ```
> $this->input->post('some_data'); The function returns FALSE (boolean)
> ```
>
> if the item you are attempting to retrieve does not exist.
>
> The second optional parameter lets you run the data through the XSS
>   filter. It's enabled by setting the second parameter to boolean TRUE;
>
> ```
> $this->input->post('some_data', TRUE); To return an array of all POST
> ```
>
> items call without any parameters.
>
> To return all POST items and pass them through the XSS filter set the
>   first parameter NULL while setting the second parameter to boolean;
>
> The function returns FALSE (boolean) if there are no items in the
>   POST.
>
> ```
> $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE); // returns all POST items with XSS
> $this->input->post(); // returns all POST items without XSS
> ```